# Volumes of unit balls in $S^2 \times\mathbb R$ and $H^2 \times\mathbb R$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, closed-form-expressions

The following integrals are equal to the volume of a unit ball in $S^2 \times \mathbb R$ and $H^2 \times\mathbb R$, respectively:

$$8\pi\int_0^1\sin^2 \frac{\sqrt{1-h^2}}2 \, dh$$

$$8\pi\int_0^1\sinh^2 \frac{\sqrt{1-h^2}}2 \, dh$$

Is a closed-form expression known for either?

Comment: Can you provide some of the calculations that led you to these integrals?

Comment: While I can easily guess that $S^2$ is the standard two-sphere, is the not-blackboard-bold $R$ the real line? And is $H^2$ the standard hyperbolic two-space?

Comment: Do you have any response to the answer below?

Comment: The spherical case agrees with the decimal approximation given by Wolfram|Alpha, but for the hyperbolic case the 1 in front should be negative.

Comment: @DanielSebald : I have now added a numerical verification of the results with Mathematica. WolframAlpha confirms the "hyperbolic" result as well: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7BNIntegrate%5BCosh%5Bx%5D+x%2FSqrt%5B1+-+x%5E2%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+1%7D%5D%2C1+%2B+1%2F2+%5C%5BPi%5D+StruveL%5B1%2C+1%5D+%2F%2F+N%7D Finally, there is a (simple) proof, to which I have now added a detail concerning the hyperbolic case. So, everything I have tried only confirms both results. Do you have any further concerns on this?

Answer (score 5):

Since $\sin^2 u=(1-\cos 2u)/2$ and $\sinh^2 u=(\cosh 2u-1)/2$, after the substitution $x=\sqrt{1-h^2}$ the two integrals respectively reduce to the integrals
$$\int_0^1\frac{x \cos x\,dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\quad\text{and}\quad
\int_0^1\frac{x \cosh x\,dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$
In turn, integrating by parts, we get
$$\int_0^1\frac{x \cos x\,dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
=1-\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}\sin x\,dx
=1-\frac\pi2\,\mathbf{H}_1(1),$$
where $\mathbf{H}$ is the [Struve function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function#Integral_form).
Similarly,
$$\int_0^1\frac{x \cosh x\,dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
=1+\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}\sinh x\,dx
=1+\frac\pi2\,\mathbf{L}_1(1),$$
where $\mathbf{L}$ is the modified Struve function.

---

**Added in response to a comment by the OP:** Here is a numerical verification of the above results with Mathematica:

[image]